# How to embed cylinder into affine space

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

View cylinder as the Riemannian surface $\mathbb{C}/ \mathbb{Z}$, how does one embed it into affine space holomorphically?

It is well known by the maximum principle that there is no holomorphic embedding of compact complex into the affine space $\mathbb C^n$. I’am trying to find some noncompact complex manifold that also can not embed into the affine space.

Comment: This question would benefit from added context, and will likely be closed otherwise. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: @user1729 sorry，actually it looks likes a homework，I just want to consider some example about embedding the riemannian surface into the affine space.

Comment: @user1729 after I post the question，I realize that f（z）=e^z give the embedding and I answer the question by myself. But my answer disappear，I quite confuse about what happening now.

Comment: Its not about homework, but really about *why* you want to do this, and what kind of things you know. For example, is it part of a larger problem, or were you thinking about something else and this question cropped up naturally?

Comment: (For your deleted answer: you need to explain *why* it is an embedding. Saying "I think $f(x)=e^z$ should be an embedding" isn't a useful answer. So you should try and add in some reasoning. On the other hand, if you are unsure how to prove this then you could add it to your question, which would be a decent improvement to it.)

Comment: @user1729 I got it，thank you！

Answer (score 1):

the function $f(z)=e^z$ give the embedding.More presicely, we can assume the cylinder is just a region in complex plane with $Im(z)$ belong to$[0,2\pi)$,since f is periodic and its period is actually $2\pi$ in the imaginary part.it is easy to find that $logz$ give the inverse of f.

A famous theorem claim that every noncompact riemannian surface is stein, which means that every noncompact riemannian surface can be embed into the affine space.So if the manifold exists,it's complex dimension must be bigger than 1.

Comment: Certainly the cylinder does not embed (even continuously) in $\Bbb C$. I presume you meant $e^{2\pi i z}$, but this still isn’t going to work.

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry，I think， for injective $e^z=1$ implys z=$2ikπ$ .And $e^z$ is continuous and open map since it is holomorphic. Why this material do not obtain the embedding？

Comment: The Stein manifolds are supposed to embed as *closed* submanifolds, are they not? Your map is certainly not proper, as the origin is a limit point of the image.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think if we view the cylinder $S_1×（0，1）$ as a cone with its summit be cut off. It's quiet easy to embed it into $\mathbb{C}$ by projection.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Oh，here the embedding is not need to be closed embedding . Maybe my example of stein manifold mislead you，sorry.

Comment: @TedShifrin Actually there are no close embedding from cylinder to $C$ by the invariant of domain.